# Qt4: Write a function that creates a dialog and returns the choice of the user

Tags: python, user-interface, qt

Not sure if this has a straightforward solution, but I want to write a function that shows a dialog (defined elsewhere in a class that inherits `QDialog`) and returns the user input when the user has finished interacting with the dialog. In other words, something similar to the `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` static method, where a single line can open the dialog and return the user's input, instead of employing the cumbersome (in this case) signal/slot mechanism.

Intended use:

```
/* Shows the dialog, waits until user presses OK or Cancel,
   then returns the user's choice. 
*/

result = createDialogAndReturnUserChoice()
```

I am currently working in PyQt but I'm fine with answers in the traditional Qt4 C++ framework.

EDIT//

Here's how to do it:

```
dialog = CustomDialog() # creates the custom dialog we have defined in a class inheriting QDialog
if dialog.exec_(): # on exec_(), the whole program freezes until the user is done with the dialog; it returns the response of the user
   # success
else:
   # failure
```

Comment: [QInputDialog](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qinputdialog.html)?

Comment: I want to use a custom dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have everything in place that you need. You can make a static function in your `QDialog` derived class that does what you want. You can create a struct or class that encapsulates the data the user will generate and return it from your static function. Qt includes all the source code so you can look at `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` in `qfiledialog.cpp` and see what they do.

**Edit:** Sorry, I missed that you are working in Python. I don't know what facilities the language has for extending a C++ class and static methods.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the source code and then learned about the exec() function that does exactly what I want.